# Ajax search wont run

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdo

I've upload my script to Fiddle and can be find here: http://jsfiddle.net/XdPk5/1/

I just can't seem to get it running, I'm trying to add errors, such as row count = 0 and if empty post has been sent

javascript:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".search").click(function(){
                $.post(
                    "search.php", 
                    { keywords: $(".keywords").val() }, 
                      function(data) {
                        $("div#search").empty();
                        obj = JSON.parse(data);
                        $("div#search").append(obj.id + " " + obj.title);
                      },
                    "json"
                );
            });
        });
```

php:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db','root','');

$keywords = (isset($_POST['keywords']) === true) ? $_POST['keywords'] : '';
if (empty($keywords) === true) {
    echo json_encode( "error" );

} else {
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT `media`.`id`, `media`.`title` FROM `media` WHERE `media`.`title` LIKE :keywords");

    if ($query->rowCount() == 0) {
        echo 'empty';

    } else {
        $query->bindValue(':keywords', '%' . $keywords . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $arr = array();
        $query->execute();
        while( $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
            $arr[] = array( "id" => $row["id"], "title" => $row["title"]);
        }
        echo json_encode( $arr );
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: You should add your javascript and php to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT `media`.`id`, `media`.`title` FROM `media` WHERE `media`.`title` LIKE :keywords");

if ($query->rowCount() == 0) {
    echo 'empty';

} else {
    $query->bindValue(':keywords', '%' . $keywords . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

- There is no `rowCount` before you execute the query;
- If there are multiple words entered, you would need to build your sql query adding the individual keyword and chaining them together using `OR` or `AND`.

Also, where you do `echo 'empty';` you are not returning valid json.

In the javascript, you probably mean `dataType: "json"` instead of just `"json"` as that is not a valid option.

Comment: I'm really stuck and just going to give up. Thanks though.